# Update database onclick using ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to be able to update the database when I click on a li item but I am having a hard time to find an answer to this question. I know there are hundreds of similar questions but I haven't been able to get an answer specific to my question, for use with laravel.

This is my route for updating the database:

```
Route::post('api/tasks/update/{id}', function($id) {
    $task = App\Task::find($id);

    $task->completed = Request::get('completed');

    $task->save();
});
```

I just have an unordered list with some li's on my view, and once clicked on one of those views, I want to set a specific value in the database to either `0` or `1`.

Here is my database table for tasks:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

As you can see it is a simple `id` field, `name` field and `completed` field. My view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        <li>{!! $task->name !!}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

So I basically only need a pointer in the right direction for the actual AJAX call.

Comment: Are you just looking for the jQuery `$.post()` function?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what the ajax call should look like since I am not into javascript at all

Comment: Assign the unique id to each <li> and using "on" function of jQuery as you content will generate dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a `GET` request, to make a call ajax, first bind the id to the `li` element

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    <li data-id='{!! $task->id !!}'>{!! $task->name !!}</li>
@endforeach
```

and use this jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/tasks/update/'+$(this).data('id'),
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(){
            alert('success');
        });
    }); 
})
```

and finally, change your route from post to get.

```
 Route::get(...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed, from this I can get it to work, thank you!